# Concat of variables causes "template error while templating string: unexpected '/'"

Tags: ansible

When I try to concat strings from variables which contain slashes ("/") then Ansible fails.

Variables:

```
PLAY_USER_HOME: "/home/pl"
version: "1.1"
```

Tried methods for concat:

```
- debug:
    var: "{{''.join((PLAY_USER_HOME, '/pns-', version))}}"
- debug:
    var: "{{PLAY_USER_HOME}}/pns-{{version}}"
```

Both times the following error is thrown:

```
fatal: [192.168.178.25]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while 
templating string: unexpected '/'. String: {{/home/pl/pns-1.1}}"}
```

When I change the variable from `"/home/pl"` to `"_home_pl"`, then it works fine. Debug just complains about `'_home_pl' is undefined` for whatever reason:

```
ok: [192.168.178.25] => {
    "_home_pl/pns-1.1": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!: '_home_pl' is undefined"
}
```

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong? My Ansible version is 2.8.3

Thanks for any help!

Comment: This seems to affect the modules `debug` and `copy`. I created a workaround with `command` which works fine. i.e. `command: "mv {{PLAY_USER_HOME}}/pns-{{version}} {{PLAY_ROOT_PATH}}"` works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases [*`debug`*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/debug_module.html#debug-print-statements-during-execution) should use *`msg`* instead of *`var`*. Correct syntax is

```
- debug:
    msg: "{{ ''.join((PLAY_USER_HOME, '/pns-', version)) }}"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ PLAY_USER_HOME }}/pns-{{ version }}"
```

Comment: Works with `msg`. Although the problem still persists with module `copy`, which is why I used `debug`. But my question didn't include that. So your answer is technically correct. The best kind of correct. Thanks.